# Ubuntu 13.04 default icons in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, 13.04, icons

Does anyone know where can I get Unity icons set from 13.04 to install it on 12.04?

With kind regards,
Abel Dean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get them here: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=155513
But they aren't all from the new Ubuntu, some of them were designed by the author